# How to create a non-password-requesting SVN repository with VisualSVN Server

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, repository

We are currently creating a SVN repository for modules that we have created so that our partners and freelancers can download the modules and the doc, but not the source.

We are using VisualSVN Server to create and manage the repositories. I have tried two blog post explanations (http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/480534.aspx, http://ferventcoder.com/archive/2008/10/04/enhancing-visual-svn-to-allow-anonymous-access.aspx) as of how to create an anonymous repository that does not require login, but the instructions do not yield the expected results.

Anybody has another way of doing this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Exactly what goes wrong when you follow the instructions?

Comment: If I use the browser, I get prompted to enter a password. If I click cancel, I get the "401 Authorization Required" error. If I do not fill anything and click continue, it just keeps requesting the login.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why it still not implemented in VisualSVNServer config by default, but solution is easy - just add **Satisfy** declaration (and restart server after :-))

```
<Location /svn/>
  ...
  Satisfy Any
  require valid-user
</Location>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Stackoverflow always saves the day. ;)